# Why does JpaRepository return an empty set for this One-to-Many relation?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data

I have two entities in a One-to-Many relation. Creating, updating and deleting work as expected. However, when I read the entities from the database, the relation field is left as an empty set instead of containing the objects from the database.

These are the two entities in question:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "point_in_time")
class PointInTime(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val note: String
) {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "symptom", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var symptoms: Set<Symptom> = emptySet()
    @field:Column(updatable = false)
    val createdAt: Instant = Instant.now()
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "symptom")
@IdClass(SymptomId::class)
class Symptom(
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "point_in_time_id", nullable = false)
    var pointInTime: PointInTime,
    @Id
    val category: String,
    @Id
    val symptom: String,
    val strength: Strength
)
```

The repository is a simple JpaRepository defined as such:

```
@Repository
interface PointInTimeRepository : JpaRepository<PointInTime, Long>
```

But the object return from calling the following method on the repository

```
repository.findByIdOrNull(id)
```

just has an empty set for `PointInTime.symptoms`

What do I have to add to get the `symptoms` field to be properly filled? I'm especially confused because creating and updating this field works properly and is persisted in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mappedBy` doesn't look correct:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "symptom", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
var symptoms: Set<Symptom> = emptySet()
```

`mappedBy` tells Hibernate to look at the `symptom` property in the Symptom class.
But in your case, it should look at `pointInTime` field instead of `symptom`.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "point_in_time_id", nullable = false)
var pointInTime: PointInTime,
```

Example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pointInTime", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
var symptoms: Set<Symptom> = emptySet()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixed it. I misunderstood the mappedBy attribute and thought it refered to the table name.